# es6 modules in angular rails app using sprockets-es6 to do transpilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ecmascript-6, sprockets

we are using [sprockets-es6](https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6) to transpile our angular es6 code in our rails-angular app. There seems to be some issues w/ using the es6 modules, I think maybe because sprockets-es6 transpiles to commonJS which causes modules to not work in the browser? Code looks like:

```
class DirtyAwareModel {
 ... some code
}

export { DirtyAwareModel };
```

and imported in a separate file/class like:

```
import { DirtyAwareModel } from './DirtyAwareModel';

class SnippetModel extends DirtyAwareModel {
  ... some code
}

SnippetModel.$inject = ['SnippetResource', 'PristineTracker', '$q'];
angular.module('selfalyticsServices.snippetModel', []).service('SnippetModel', SnippetModel);
```

I get an error in dirty_aware_model.js.self.js:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

the error being thrown here in the transpiled code:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
```

Comment: Hello, Were you able to get through this one ?

Comment: we ended up using angular dependency injection